# joomla 3.3 css module overriding doesn't work

Tags: html, css, joomla, overriding, joomla3.0

I have use the backend feaure to create an override for the module djmenu. This automatically create the folder `mod_djmenu` in `template/protostar/html` and create a `default.php` in this folder.

I want to override the `djmenu.css` which is originally placed in `module/mod_djmenu/themes/default/css`, so I created in `template/protostar/html/mod_djmenu` the folder `themes/default/css` and copy paste the `djmenu.css` there.

I changed some simple but obvious CSS properties (background...) to test the override but it's not changing anything on my website and when I use firebug I still that the original file is used and not the override. I went across several tutorials but without success.

What I am missing?

Comment: try important tag to override in case you are having issue. Otherwise the best UI approach is to giving css specificity(i.e., giving more specific styles to the elements).

Comment: Thnaks for your help Steeve. I did try !important without success though. I am not sure what you mean by "more specific style to the elements".

Comment: Say, if you are overriding a class called .container inside a table row, you can give it by more specific table > tbody tr.container. rather that giving a plain class of .container. Sounds good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do to make the css overrides work (it's working for the dj-menu module only not every modules though)

1) copy paste the css files you want to override in the `template/protostar/css` folder

2) in dj-menu module setting, select `- override from template -` on the theme field (first tab in the module page).